# Why does this affect framerate?

Tags: java, optimization, slick2d

I have a small game I'm making for fun and I noticed after a few hours of coding my framerate was hovering around 120 even though I don't have much going on in the game. I eventually narrowed it down to the shop system when the name of a shop item is rendered. Heres the code:

```
public void render(Graphics g, Image img, int x, int y) {
    img.getScaledCopy(255, 64).draw(x, y);
    g.setFont(Fonts.pt32);
    g.drawString(name, x + 64 + 8, y);
}
```

On a hunch I tried making the name variable which was just a private String, static and the framerate jumped back up to ~800. Can someone explain why this happens?
Also I can't keep it static so I need a way to get around this.

EDIT I just noticed If I reload the game while it's running the framerate returns to normal? Why is that? When I reload ir recreates the shop by adding each element to an ArrayList which I forgot to reset when it's reloaded. After reloading the game will render All of the shop elements twice and it runs faster???

Comment: Most likely (but you didn't provide enough info to be sure here), that's an issue with multithreading.

Comment: Is changing `name` to `final` makes any difference?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using Slick2D which Double Buffers by default.
@AdamStelmaszczyk It has the same effect as just using static.

Comment: In addition to that: Is declaring it `volatile`?

Comment: Is this a method on your Shop class?  How many Shop objects do you have?

Comment: @Ephyxia final and static are 2 different things. The compiler cannot optimize static variables as much, because the value may change at runtime, which by definition can't happen with a final.

Comment: Scaling is an expensive operation at the best of times. Have you tried buffering the result of the scale an only rending it instead of scaling each time render is called..

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I have 11 shop objects